# Linear gradient causes banding in chrome

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am facing issue with linear gradient in chrome. Here is my code

```css
div{
  background: linear-gradient(20deg, rgb(213, 213, 55), rgb(158, 158, 33));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(20deg, rgb(213, 213, 55), rgb(158, 158, 33));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(20deg, rgb(213, 213, 55), rgb(158, 158, 33));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(20deg, rgb(213, 213, 55), rgb(158, 158, 33));
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

While using gradient some banding occuring in chrome. Gradient not look smooth on chrome. Here is screenshot for same.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: The gradient looks perfectly smooth for me. What version of Chrome do you use? Can you maybe capture a screenshot of the banding?

Comment: I have added image above. I am using chrome 54.0.2840.59

Comment: what you mean by banding? the output and screenshot seems normal! May be you have some problem with your Display! (check it in another pc/smartphone/display)

Comment: I don't see a noteworthy banding on the screenshot as well, looks like in Firefox ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ However, the latest Version of Chrome is 61.0.3163.100, you may want to upgrade and take a look again.

Comment: I have tested on onther machine. I can see the banding in screenshot and in html also. Anyone have any idea what could I do?

Comment: No apparent banding - Chrome Version 62.0.3202.29 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)

Comment: Silly question...this isn't a question of the *angle* is it?

Comment: I facing problem with my chrome version that's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use 2 layers. From color to transparent, and superimpose them on each other:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(20deg, rgb(213, 213, 55), transparent);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(20deg, transparent, rgb(158, 158, 33));
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```